# Почему "наказанный" с двумя Н?

Tags: причастие

Почему *наказа**нн**ый* пишется всегда с двумя Н? Потому что есть приставка *на-*? Так нет слова *казанный*, и глагол *казать* уже не используется.

Comment: Почему-то этот вопрос продублировался и было создано два вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С двумя Н пишутся причастия, образованные от глагола совершенного вида, в данном случае от глагола "наказать"